# Passing objects to methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have corrected something that was confusing me in `V2` but am still a little curious as to what `V1` is doing. Looking at `V1` now am I right in thinking that line is being passed by value (so essentially what I have is a local copy of line). Scanner then scans its data into the address of that local copy, the local copy is destroyed when the method exits and the external variable line is still nil?

On `V2`, I am passing the address of line and then scanning data into that address, is this using passing by reference, just not sure of the terminology?

```
// V1
NSString *line = nil;
[self scanUsing:scanner into:line];
NSLog(@"AFTER_: %@", line);

- (void)scanUsing:(NSScanner *)scanner into:(NSString *)line {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&line];
    NSLog(@"INSIDE: %@", line);
}
```

.

```
// V2     
NSString *line = nil;
[self scanUsing:scanner into:&line];
NSLog(@"AFTER_: %@", line);

- (void)scanUsing:(NSScanner *)scanner into:(NSString **)line {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:line];
    NSLog(@"INSIDE: %@", *line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V1

You are passing a copy of the pointer. It points to the same memory region, so what you see is the same value. You are passing the object then, by value. You can change the content, but not create a new object, since that pointer wont exist when the method finishes.

V2

Definition of reference is different (its a C++ type) But yeah, lets say that it behaves more or less the same. In V2 a new object can be allocated inside the method, and therefore, you can change the memory region that is being pointed by it.

So:

- V1, passing by value. You pass the pointer, and can change the content of the object pointed by the pointer.
- V2, passing by reference. You pass a pointer to a pointer, and therefore you can alloc memory, and so change the pointer address as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not C++, you can't call it pass-by-reference. You can, however, call it pass-by-pointer. (Which is still by value, but you're passing a *pointer* by value.)

Apart from grammar nazi: the first version modifies only the local copy of `line` (i. e. the one inside the function); the one you actually passed in stays unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

In V1, you're changing the value of the `line` local parameter, which only exists in the scope of the method, you're not changing your global `line` variable.

In V2, you effectively pass the global `line` pointer by reference, which allows you to change its value...

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are passing a reference to an object.
In the second example, you are passing a reference to a reference of an object.

If you log the line-object in the first example, you would see difference, while in the second you would see the object you have set inside the method.

this is often used for NSError, where you have a basic return type, but you also want to notify if there was an error. You pass then a pointer to your error variable, and they pass it the reference to the NSError object. I hope this made at least a little sense to you :)